# Recommendations on SaaS architecture books?

Tags: architecture

Does anyone have any suggestions on good books on Software as as Service (SaaS) architecture? My company is looking to start providing a platform product and are looking for examples of architecture design implementations. (One important thing to note is that we'll be using Azure as our cloud provider.)

Comment: it is a valid question, just because the answer is not code doesn't mean it is not suppose to be on stack overflow, it is a proper question on Azure Documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some suggested reading material for an Azure Service Provider to start on to get a feel of the scenarios they could accomplish. I would recommend video material than a book as you get to ramp up quick and has high replay-ability.

**All the MVP Talks about Azure on Channel 9,** The talks focus on interesting scenarios and cases that MVPs tackled with the help of Azure : https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MVP-Azure

**Most of the Azure Data Exposed Shows,** As a SaaS provider you will have to decide where and how to keep the customer data, the show offers a lot of interesting ways to save data from a small company to a huge big data mining level, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed

**Power Apps and Flow Training,** *you will have to stitch some solutions together and give a simple mobile experience* during your time with your customer, a handy tool that works surprising well are Flow and Power apps, What ever you do on flow can be upgraded into a Azure Functions app to scale to Production but you can start with flow to get the POC rolling, https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PowerApps-and-Flow-Training

Stay up to date with these shows,

**Cloud Cover :** https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover

**Azure Fridays :** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday/

Hope this helps, Happy Coding with Azure !